# Converting a parameter to a floating point number in AWK

Tags: awk, floating-point

I have this code that works fine:

```
time1=23245321;
ratio=0.9761;
time1=int(time1*ratio);
```

but I get it not to work when I transform the 'ratio' variable to a parameter passed to the script with the -v option - time1 results to be equal to 0 (zero).

awk -f script.awk -v ratio=0.9761

It seems ratio is no longer treated as a float. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does script.awk contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a 'locale' issue: I should have called the script using

```
awk -f script.awk -v ratio=0,9761
```

because the comma is the decimal separator on my laptop

Comment: You could just set `LC_ALL=C` first and then use your original script.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on my machine:

```
awk -v ratio=0.9761 '{
time1=23245321;
time1=int(time1*ratio);
print ratio,time1}' <(echo "Hello world!")
```

It returns:

```
0.9761 22689757
```